# リフレッシュトークンによるidトークン再発行の実装方法

Tags: oauth, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

AWSのcognitoにてidトークンによる認証をおこなっています。
その中でトークンの有効期限が切れた場合に、リフレッシュトークンを用いてidトークンの再発行を行い、httpリクエストを継続できるような実装を考えております。

上記を実現しようとした際、idトークンの有効期限はクライアントのクッキー(メモリ)に保持しておき、有効期限が切れていたら、リフレッシュトークンを用いてidの再発行をサーバ(aws)にリクエストするのがベストプラクティスでしょうか。
しかし、それだと毎回httpリクエストの前にidトークンの有効期限をチェックしなければいけないのでその方法がいいか気になり質問させていただきました。

Comment: cognitoの場合がどうかは知りませんがリフレッシュトークンを併用するOAuth等では一般にトークンの有効期限は目安でしかなくそれを無視してトークンが失効する場合があるので401ベースでリフレッシュするのが推奨されることが多かったかと。(もちろんホントは両方意識すべきではあるのでしょうが)

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/101728

Answer (score 0):

いま手元にコードがないので、うろ覚えですが、cognitoのgetSession（だったかな？）メソッドを呼べば必要に応じてRefreshもやってくれます。
また、これもうろ覚えです、useCodeGrantFlowを呼ばないとRefreshはできないはずです。
これらをキーワードにしてググってみてください。